# SwiftUI - closing modal by swipe is breaking view constraints

Tags: swiftui

I have an issue in SwiftUI with modals combined with custom backgrounds.

If I move the app into the background when a modal is open (e.g. home button on the simulator), then returning the app back to the foreground and closing the modal via swipe, the main screen constraints are broken.

The rendering is correct but the click responding constraints are off.

See screenshots about the constraints before moving the app to the background and after moving it back to the foreground:

[image][image]

Here is the code to reproduce the issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var modal = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Spacer()
            Button{ modal = true } label: {
                Text("Show modal")
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        )
        .sheet(isPresented: $modal, content: {
            Text("modal")
        })
    }
}
```

Am I applying any of the modifiers incorrectly or this is an iOS bug?

I have tried to apply the modifiers in a different order but it did not help.

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Comment: @patrikbelis - Unfortunately not :/

Comment: @patrikbelis I can not reproduce the issue using iPhone 14 Pro simulator. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini tbh i never tested it on simulator only on device. You have some SwiftUI View, you open any modal screen. You go to background, open back, close modal and clickable action contraints are off. (for ex. Buttons)

Comment: Tested on my iPhone Xs iOS 17 Beta2 with no issues ‍♂️ @patrikbelis

Comment: Probably was fixed in ios 17? @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: Tested on my iPhone 11 iOS 16.0 with no issues I think we can call this "not reproducable"

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini It is still reproducible on iOS 16.5.1

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it's the `.contentShape` inside `Button`. The following works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var modal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Spacer()
            Button{ modal = true } label: {
                Text("Show modal")
//                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // reduce to minimum
        .background(
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        )
        .sheet(isPresented: $modal, content: {
            Text("modal")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The `contentShape` is added only to improve the click-field of the text button. It does not changes anything related to the issue. It is still present without that modifier